# Migrate wordpress to drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal, migrate

I want to migrate my wordpress site to drupal.  With my broken wordpress site, I only have access to the mysql database.  i.e, no wp-admin backend access.  Is there any way to migrate the site just by using the db dump?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to fix the problem with the Wordpress database. It's possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to migrate WordPress to Drupal 8 with the WordPress database.

You need to install [Wp Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wp_migrate) module
For that, and You need [migration tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migration_tools) module and [migrate plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus) module along with the core migration module.

For more information refer the below links.

https://dev.acquia.com/blog/wordpress-drupal-8-migration
https://github.com/amitgoyal/d8_migrate_wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to exporting the wordpress site, there is a module for the migration called [WordPress Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate).

> wordpress_migrate supports migrating WordPress blog exports (WXR format) into Drupal using the [Migrate module](https://drupal.org/project/migrate). Import of posts, pages, comments, attachments, tags and categories is supported. Imports can be rolled back completely.

But, as you say that you don't have access to export, then probably you'll have to put in some (coding) effort in implementing it via the [Migrate module](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) itself.

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands (strongly recommended).

It seems difficult in the beginning, however there is an [extensive documentation](https://drupal.org/node/415260) which guides you through the process.